# Android create notification automatically

Tags: java, android, notifications, task

I want to create a notification in my app , when data downloaded from API changes.

Example:

- I want to create a notification when a Twitch streamer start
  streaming.
- I want to create a notification when a Twitter user posts a new
  tweet.
- I want to create a notification when a YouTube user uploads a new
  video.

How can I do this? Periodically download data and check changes? How do I create this task if the application is destroyed or the device is restarted? How do I do it so I do not discharge the device's battery too much?

I know how to download data and how create a notification, but I don't now how to create the described task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best practice here is using push notification.
all you have to do is registering you app with one of the well known providers of the service like FireBase Cloud Messaging and then configure your app's server to send notifications to the Cloud Messaging service which will handle the delivering of your notification

and you won't have to worry about battery usage because they use google play services to keep a connection open and they even display the notification themselves.
they provide many other features you can use and they are optimized in the best possible way.

you don't have to reinvent the wheel